# Android crashing nothing in logcat

Tags: android, xml, crash, drawable, xml-drawable

https://github.com/BeniReydman/Slide_Menu-Slide_Menu If anyone would like to see if they can get crash logs themselves that would really help.

I tested it out and it keeps crashing when I run a certain function.

I have removed the function and ran the app perfectly so I can say with certainty that this is the cause of it. I put everything the function is involved in, any left out detail is unimportant.

```
public void function(){
    if(this >= that1){
        button1.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        button1.setEnabled(true);
    }
    if(this >= that2){
        button2.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        button2.setEnabled(true);
    }
    if(this >= that3){
        button3.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        button3.setEnabled(true);
    }
    if(this >= that4){
        button4.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        button4.setEnabled(true);
    }
}

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/buttongray"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/buttonclick" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button" android:state_enabled="false"></item>

</selector>
```

**More Code**

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="4">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_state2_xml"
            android:id="@+id/upgbutton"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_state3_xml"
            android:id="@+id/upgbutton1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_state4_xml"
            android:id="@+id/upgbutton2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_state5_xml"
            android:id="@+id/upgbutton3"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


            </LinearLayout>
```

**and at the beginning of oncreateview**

```
public void setButton() {
        button1 = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.upgbutton);
        button2 = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.upgbutton1);
        button3 = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.upgbutton2);
        button4 = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.upgbutton3);
    }
```

**code for fragment**

**Function is called cookieChange**

```
View.OnClickListener mStartListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (loop == 0) {
                mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                mChronometer.start();
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                loop++;
            } else if (loop == 1) {
                millis = System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime;
                mChronometer.stop();
                Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Your Time is: " + (millis/1000);
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 25);
                toast.show();
                cookieStr();
                loop++;
            } else if (loop == 2) {
                mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                cookieCalc();
                TextView myText = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                myText.setText("= " + cookies);
                TextView myText2 = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.editText);
                myText2.setText("Stop Watch as Close as Possible to 5");
                cookieChange();
                loop = 0;
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Please include more code to let me know what is this and that here ?

Comment: this and that I changed because it's just me figuring out if the amount of currency they have is more then he cost. Basically I am editing upgrades so when they don't have enough it will stay gray. As soon as they earn cookies it runs the function again to check to see if they have enough and once they do it will change it to true. This rarely happens only when the user recieves currency.

Comment: Can you please show me complete code of your Fragemnet which has method named function().

Comment: I put it the function is actually called cookieChange(); second last command. The entire app works fine if I do //cookieChange(); and it never runs it. I posted everything that involves cookieChange above. Also button1-4 are already declared incase you were wondering.

Comment: I am still confused at this line if(this >= that1) , what is "this" and "that1" here , Can you please explain .

Comment: By default in java "this" is the object ,so you can't perform >= on "this" .

Comment: It must have error logs,try execute this in command line: 
 `adb logcat AndroidRuntime:* *:S`,then i think you can see the error logs,and show us to make the question more clearly.

Comment: https://github.com/BeniReydman/Slide_Menu-Slide_Menu I can't properly check. Also this is probably easier for everyone if I just post my code.